# Does storing objects in a std::vector increase the lifetime of the object ?

Tags: c++, memory-management, stdvector

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    { 
        nueron temp; // my Class
        _inputNuerons.push_back(temp); // _inputNuerons is a std::vector 
    }
```

From what I know , C++ deallocates the temp object when it reaches the } bracket of the for loop.
But does storing the object in a std::vector make the object usable later on in the program ? 
Now when I try to access the "temp" nueron outside the for loop , the program crashes.

How can I store my objects in a std::vector such that it is usable later on ?

Comment: Knowing quite-literally *nothing* about your code, the best you're going to get are wags (wild-ass-guesses). Here's mine: `nueron` isn't [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) compliant, and needs to be. Another likely possibility, `_inputNuerons` resizes during the course of your for-loop, and all those prior-saved addresses in previous iterations are now bogus. Now, [Post a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your crash, please.

Comment: @WhozCraig I have tried to post an MCVE. I will try to make nueron Rule of Three compliant and repost. Thank you .

Comment: You are not storing `temp` in the `vector`.  Rather, you are creating a *copy* of it in there.  If your program crashes when accessing that copy, you probably have a bug in your `neuron`'s copy constructor, bu we cannot see that unless you are showing us the code.  Attempting to access `temp` (eg via a pointer you are assigning `temp`'s address to) outside the loop body is undefined behavior.

Comment: @5gon12eder yep what you said is right. I was thinking that storing is what happens. Thanks. I will have to make neuron rule of 3 compliant.

Comment: Even if your class *is* R03 compliant, then your prior code was actually more telling. Pushing addresses of elements in a vector into another container and having the vector resize invalidates *all* the prior addresses already retrieved. That was the crux of my second wag. In short, `_outputNueron.setInputNueron(&_inputNuerons[i], ..)` - if that address is stored to be later used, it will be junk as soon as `_inputNuerons` resizes for whatever reason (like a `push_back`).

Comment: @WhozCraig thank you for pointing it out. I will try to see what I can do about it.

Comment: `resize` would be one way (and lose the push_back), or `reserve` to avoid implicit resizing during your accumulation. If you know the size ahead of time, that is.

Answer (score 1):

Your neuron object will be destroyed at the end of for block.
You should use dynamic allocation, and store the pointer on that object in vector.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{ 
    nueron* temp = new neuron(); // my Class
    _inputNuerons.push_back(temp); // _inputNuerons is a std::vector 
}
```

_inputNeurons collection should be collection of neuron pointers.

Comment: While, technically, this “solves” the issue raised in the question, I very much doubt that this is a good idea and it probably won't solve the actual problem.

Comment: Your answer solves the problem . But the actual error was because I did not follow the rule of 3. I did not create a copy constructor to copy the neuron , I did not know that a copy constructor is evoked when I store an object in the std::vector. Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

> How can I store my objects in a std::vector such that it is usable
>   later on ?

The compiler creates a copy constructor for you if you don’t provide your own (and do not delete it).

The body of the compiler-created-copy-constructor is NOT empty, and it will copy all data members of the passed nueron object (temp) to the object which is being created in the element of the vector.

Thus the following works fine:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{ 
    Nueron temp; // my Class
    _inputNuerons.push_back(temp); // _inputNuerons is a std::vector 
}
```

- new Nueron temp is constructed at the left-brace starting the loop and
- the object temp is destroyed at the right-brace ending the loop and
- the push_back copies temp (via compiler provided copy ctor) into the next element of the vector

---

Here is some code to illustrate the compiler generated default copy ctor.

Note that this default ctor provides a unique value for each Nueron.  This is just for fun and to make it easy to see that all elements are copied and initialized with compiler provided default code.

note 1 - You can size and fill a vector in the same line,
and
note 2 - you can build an element on your stack, and apply push_back().

Example code:

```
int seqNum(bool restart=false) // when true restart seqnum
{
   static int SeqNum = 0;
   if(restart) SeqNum = 0; 
   return (SeqNum++);
}

class Nueron
{
public:

   Nueron() : i1(seqNum()) {}  // you provide the default ctor 

   // default dtor - use the compiler provided dtor

   // default copy ctor - use the compiler provided copy ctor

   std::string show()
      {
         std::stringstream ss;
         ss << DTB::digiComma(i1);
         return (ss.str());
      };    

private:
   int i1;
};


void headerShow(std::stringstream& ss)
{
   ss << " vector element size: " << std::setw(5) << sizeof(Nueron) << "  bytes\n" // header
      << "\n"
      << std::setw(15) << "element"
      << std::setw(15) << "vector"
      << std::setw(20) << "bytes stack use"
      << std::setw(24) << "bytes heap use\n"

      << std::setw(15) << "  count"
      << std::setw(15) << "capacity"
      << std::setw(20) << "'sizeof(vector)'"
      << std::setw(24) << "     (element count * element size)\n";
}

void infoShow(std::vector<Nueron>& n, std::stringstream& ss)
{
   ss << std::setw(15) << DTB::digiComma(n.size())    // element count
      << std::setw(15) << DTB::digiComma(n.capacity()) // vector capacity
      << std::setw(18) << DTB::digiComma(sizeof(n))   // bytes stack use
      << std::setw(24) << DTB::digiComma (n.size() * sizeof(Nueron)) // bytes heap use
      << std::endl;
}

void contentShow(size_t               indx,
                 std::vector<Nueron>& n,
                 std::stringstream&   ss,
                 size_t               limit1,
                 size_t               limit2 = 0)
{
   ss << " content " << indx << ": ";

   for (size_t i=0; i<limit1; ++i)
      ss << n[i].show() << "  ";

   if(limit2)
   {
      ss << "...  ";
      for (size_t i=(n.size()-limit2); i<n.size(); ++i)
         ss << std::setw(10) << n[i].show() << "  ";
   }
   ss << std::endl;
}


int t207a(void)
{
   std::cout << "\n============================================= " << "\nt207a():" << std::endl;
   (void)seqNum(true); // restart seq from 0

   std::stringstream ss1;
   std::stringstream ss2;

   std::vector<Nueron> neuron(5);  // default ctor used 5 times
   headerShow(ss1);
   infoShow(neuron, ss1);

   // add 5 more using 'free' copy ctor
   for (size_t i=0; i<5; ++i)
   {
      Nueron temp;             // use ctor
      neuron.push_back(temp);  // use compiler provided copy ctor
   }
   infoShow(neuron, ss1);

   ss2 << "\n";
   contentShow(1, neuron, ss2, 10, 0);

   std::cout << ss2.str() << std::endl << ss1.str() << std::endl;

   // neuron dtor runs here
   return(0);
}
```

reports:

> =============================================  t207a():
>
> content 1: 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
>
> vector element size:     4  bytes
>
> ```
>     element         vector     bytes stack use         bytes heap use
>       count       capacity    'sizeof(vector)'     (element count * element size)
>           5              5                24                      20
>          10             10                24                      40
> ```

edit -

With respect to the other answers that might be interpreted as suggesting putting the vector itself into heap ... I have prepared the following code to illustrate why this is not necessary.

```
int t207b(void)
{
   std::cout << "\n============================================= " << "\nt207b():" << std::endl;
   (void)seqNum(true); // restart seq from 0

   std::stringstream ss1;
   std::stringstream ss2;

   std::vector<Nueron> neuron; // no elements
   headerShow(ss1);
   infoShow(neuron, ss1);

   size_t cap1 = neuron.capacity();

   // add elements using 'free' copy ctor
   do
   {
      {
         Nueron temp;             // use ctor
         neuron.push_back(temp);  // use compiler provided copy ctor
      }
      size_t cap2 = neuron.capacity();

      if(cap2 != cap1)
      {
         cap1 = cap2;

         infoShow(neuron, ss1);

         if (cap2 > 500000000) break;
         //          12345678
      }

   }while(1);
   contentShow(1, neuron, ss2, 10, 0);

   std::cout << ss1.str() << "\n" << std::endl << ss2.str() << std::endl;
   // neuron dtor runs here
   return(0);
}
```

With output:

> =============================================
>   t207b():  vector element size:     4  bytes
>
> ```
>     element         vector     bytes stack use         bytes heap use
>       count       capacity    'sizeof(vector)'     (element count * element size)
>           0              0                24                       0
>           1              1                24                       4
>           2              2                24                       8
>           3              4                24                      12
>           5              8                24                      20
>           9             16                24                      36
>          17             32                24                      68
>          33             64                24                     132
>          65            128                24                     260
>         129            256                24                     516
>         257            512                24                   1,028
>         513          1,024                24                   2,052
>       1,025          2,048                24                   4,100
>       2,049          4,096                24                   8,196
>       4,097          8,192                24                  16,388
>       8,193         16,384                24                  32,772
>      16,385         32,768                24                  65,540
>      32,769         65,536                24                 131,076
>      65,537        131,072                24                 262,148
>     131,073        262,144                24                 524,292
>     262,145        524,288                24               1,048,580
>     524,289      1,048,576                24               2,097,156
>   1,048,577      2,097,152                24               4,194,308
>   2,097,153      4,194,304                24               8,388,612
>   4,194,305      8,388,608                24              16,777,220
>   8,388,609     16,777,216                24              33,554,436
>  16,777,217     33,554,432                24              67,108,868
>  33,554,433     67,108,864                24             134,217,732
>  67,108,865    134,217,728                24             268,435,460
> 134,217,729    268,435,456                24             536,870,916
> 268,435,457    536,870,912                24           1,073,741,828
> ```

Summary - for g++ version 4.9.2, on Ubuntu 15.04:

- column 3 shows that regardless of the number of elements in the vector OR the size of the elements, the stack impact is always only 24 bytes.  (i.e. sizeof())
- column 1 and 2 show the implementations choice for vector growth (i.e. binary)
- column 4 shows total bytes in the vector.  Vector guarantees that all the elements are back to back.  In this example the code quit with 500 million element entered, and 1 GByte in (I presume) dynamic memory.

This stack impact is so small, you probably do not want to push the vector to the heap.